# How to look up values from a table and insert name of the lookup-list?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, lookup

I have a (sample)table like this:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   text="Gene  SYMBOL  Values
                   TP53            2            3.55   
                   XBP1            5            4.06
                   TP27            1            2.53
                   REDD1           4            3.99
                   ERO1L           6            5.02
                   STK11           9            3.64
                   HIF2A           8            2.96")
```

I want to look up the symbols from two different genelists, given here as genelist1 and genelist2:

```
genelist1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                        text="Gene  SYMBOL
                        P4H             10
                        PLK             7
                        TP27            1
                        KTD             11
                        ERO1L           6")

genelist2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                        text="Gene  SYMBOL
                        TP53            2
                        XBP1            5
                        BHLHB           12
                        STK11           9
                        TP27            1
                        UPK             18")
```

What I want to is to get a new column where I can see in which genelist(s) I can find each of the genes in my dataframe, but when I run the following code it is just the symbols that are repeated in the new columns.

```
df_geneinfo <- df %>% 
  join(genelist1,by="SYMBOL") %>% 
  join(genelist2, by="SYMBOL")
```

Any suggestions of how to solve this, either to make one new column with the name of the genelists, or to make one column for each of the genelists?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness (and performance with large tables, perhaps), here is a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(genelist1, genelist2), idcol = "glid")[, -"Gene"][
  setDT(df), on = "SYMBOL"][, .(glid =  toString(glid)), by = .(Gene, SYMBOL, Values)][]
```

> ```
>     Gene SYMBOL Values glid
> 1:  TP53      2   3.55    2
> 2:  XBP1      5   4.06    2
> 3:  TP27      1   2.53 1, 2
> 4: REDD1      4   3.99    1
> 5: ERO1L      6   5.02   NA
> 6: STK11      9   3.64    2
> 7: HIF2A      8   2.96   NA
> ```

`rbindlist()` creates a `data.table` from all genelists and adds a column `glid` to identify the origin of each row. The `Gene` column is ignored as the subsequent join is only on `SYMBOL`. Before joining, `df` is coerced to class `data.table` using `setDT()`. The joined result is then aggregated by `SYMBOL` to exhibit cases where a symbol appears in both genelists which is the case for `SYMBOL == 1`.

---

#### Edit

In case there are many genelists or the full name of the genelist is required instead of just a number, we can try this:

```
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^genelist")), idcol = "glid")[, -"Gene"][
  setDT(df), on = "SYMBOL"][, .(glid =  toString(glid)), by = .(Gene, SYMBOL, Values)][]
```

> ```
>     Gene SYMBOL Values                 glid
> 1:  TP53      2   3.55            genelist2
> 2:  XBP1      5   4.06            genelist2
> 3:  TP27      1   2.53 genelist1, genelist2
> 4: REDD1      4   3.99                   NA
> 5: ERO1L      6   5.02            genelist1
> 6: STK11      9   3.64            genelist2
> 7: HIF2A      8   2.96                   NA
> ```

`ls()`is looking for objects in the environment the name of which is starting with `genelist...`. `mget()` returns a named list of those objects which is passed to `rbindlist()`.

#### Data

As provided by the OP

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("TP53", "XBP1", "TP27", "REDD1", "ERO1L", 
"STK11", "HIF2A"), SYMBOL = c(2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 8L), Values = c(3.55, 
4.06, 2.53, 3.99, 5.02, 3.64, 2.96)), .Names = c("Gene", "SYMBOL", 
"Values"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
genelist1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("P4H", "PLK", "TP27", "KTD", "ERO1L"), 
    SYMBOL = c(10L, 7L, 1L, 11L, 4L)), .Names = c("Gene", "SYMBOL"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
genelist2 <- structure(list(Gene = c("TP53", "XBP1", "BHLHB", "STK11", "TP27", 
"UPK"), SYMBOL = c(2L, 5L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 18L)), .Names = c("Gene", 
"SYMBOL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote my own function, which replaces the column values:

```
replace_by_lookuptable <- function(df, col, lookup) {
  assertthat::assert_that(all(col %in% names(df))) # all cols exist in df
  assertthat::assert_that(all(c("new", "old") %in% colnames(lookup)))

  cond_na_exists <- is.na(unlist(lapply(df[, col], function(x) my_match(x, lookup$old))))
  assertthat::assert_that(!any(cond_na_exists))

  df[, col] <- unlist(lapply(df[, col], function(x) lookup$new[my_match(x, lookup$old)]))
  return(df)
}
```

`df` is the data.frame, `col` is a vector of column names which should be replaced using `lookup`, a data.frame with column "old" and "new".

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `listid` column to your genelists

```
genelist1$listid = 1
genelist2$listid = 2
```

you can then merge your df with the genelists:

```
merge(df,rbind(genelist1,genelist2),all.x=T, by = "SYMBOL")
```

Note that ERO1L is SYMBOL 6 in your df and 4 in genelist1, and HIF2A and REDD1 are missing from genelists but REDD1 is symbol 4 in your df (which is ERO1L in genlist1... so I'm a not sure of what output you're expecting in that case.

You could also merge only on Gene names:

```
merge(df,rbind(genelist1,genelist2),all.x=T, by.x = "Gene", by.y= "Gene")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of your genlists in a `list`:

```
gen_list <- list(genelist1 = genelist1,genelist2 = genelist2)
```

and compare them to your target `data.frame`:

```
cbind(df,do.call(cbind,lapply(seq_along(gen_list),function(x) ifelse( df$Gene %in% gen_list[[x]]$Gene,names(gen_list[x]),NA))))
```